# Render Latex symbols in Plotly graphs in VSCode Interactive Window

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, plotly, latex

I am trying to get Latex symbols in titles and labels of a Plotly figure.
I am using VSCode and I run the code in Interactive Window.
Latex usage looks really simple in Jupyter Notebook, from what I saw in other posts, but I can't get it to work within this environment.

My env:

python 3.10.4

plotly 5.9.0

vscode 1.62.3

What I tried:

- use r"$$" formatting,
- change the font family
- change plotly.io.renderers.default
- install mathjax in my conda env and try to adapt plotly.offline mode (see https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/issues/515)

This basic code snippet should work according to most posts I have seen but does not do the Latexrendering in the Interactive Window.
It has been taken from https://plotly.com/python/LaTeX/, where everything looks so easy. That's why I am guessing the issue is related to VSCode.

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=[1, 2, 3, 4],
    y=[1, 4, 9, 16],
    name=r'$\alpha_{1c} = 352 \pm 11 \text{ km s}^{-1}$'
))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=[1, 2, 3, 4],
    y=[0.5, 2, 4.5, 8],
    name=r'$\beta_{1c} = 25 \pm 11 \text{ km s}^{-1}$'
))
fig.update_layout(
    xaxis_title=r'$\sqrt{(n_\text{c}(t|{T_\text{early}}))}$',
    yaxis_title=r'$d, r \text{ (solar radius)}$'
)
fig.show()
```

What I have
[image: What I have]

What I should have
[image: Expected]

Comment: What should your example codes look like after running? Can it be shown in the article

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I edited the post to add link to Plotly doc and expected figure.

Comment: In VSC, I see the appropriate content (your second image). It's not related to VSC. It's more likely related to MathJax. I know anaconda/conda is popular but...umm... {full body shudder} I don't have that on my computer...because I'm not a fan. (That's as nice as I can put that into words...) You may want to utterly separate your VSC from conda. Mathjax is included with Plotly, so that's why it's odd that you're not seeing it. Are you using Workspace? (I'm not.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known issue with Plotly in Jupyter notebooks in VSCode (e.g. issues [#7801](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/7801) and #[8131](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/8131)).

Tomas Mazak shared [a workaround in #8131](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/8131#issuecomment-1589961116):

```py
import plotly
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from IPython.display import display, HTML

## Tomas Mazak's workaround
plotly.offline.init_notebook_mode()
display(HTML(
    '<script type="text/javascript" async src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.1/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_SVG"></script>'
))
##

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=[1, 2, 3, 4],
    y=[1, 4, 9, 16],
    name=r'$\alpha_{1c} = 352 \pm 11 \text{ km s}^{-1}$'
))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=[1, 2, 3, 4],
    y=[0.5, 2, 4.5, 8],
    name=r'$\beta_{1c} = 25 \pm 11 \text{ km s}^{-1}$'
))
fig.update_layout(
    xaxis_title=r'$\sqrt{(n_\text{c}(t|{T_\text{early}}))}$',
    yaxis_title=r'$d, r \text{ (solar radius)}$'
)
fig.show()
```

Output:
[image: Correctly displayed LaTeX labels]